# Is it possible to use ssh tunnel with OpenStack4j

Tags: java, openstack

I'm trying to get tenant details from Open Stack API. API's after authentication are changed to to "internalURL" by default. I'm able to override to admin by using perspective method. However, I need to use SSL tunnel and want the endpoint to use localhost:55358 for subsequent API calls. How can I achieve that?

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder().endpoint("http://localhost:55358/v2.0").credentials("user", "pass").tenantName("admin").authenticate().perspective(Facing.ADMIN);

Tenant tenant = os.identity().tenants().get("0374e503158f4d75ad3342185e06f218");
```

Console O/P

End point is changed to admin url
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > GET https://os-identity.vip.abc.com:35357/v2.0/tenants/0374e503158f4d75ad3342185e06f218
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > User-Agent: OpenStack4j / OpenStack Client

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in Java docs of OSFactory

OSFactory.enableLegacyEndpointHandling(true);